# При отводе мышки цвет ссылки должен остаться серый - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть Меню при наведении на которое оно выделяется серым цветом,в нем есть субменю, когда уводишь мышку на субменю цвет серый пропадает и становится белым. Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы когда отводишь мышку цвет меню оставался серым???

```css
ul {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 z-index: 2;
}
ul:after {
 display: block;
 content: ' ';
 clear: both;
 z-index:2;
}
ul.menu > li {
 font-size: 14px;
 border: 0;
 font-family: 'OnePlusOne 2015';
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width:25%;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border: 0px solid #f3f3f3;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 z-index:2;
}
ul.menu > li > a {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 40px;
 width:100%;
 color: #727272;
 background-color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu > li > a:hover {
 background-color:  #f3f3f3;
}
ul.submenu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 40px;
 left: 0px;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border: none;
}
ul.submenu > li {
 display: block;
}
ul.submenu > li > a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}
ul.submenu > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #ff002d;
 color: white;
 transition: 1s;
}
ul.menu > li:hover > ul.submenu {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
   <li class="menu-program"><a class="menu-link" href="#">Програми <img src="img/Rectangle 43 copy 10.png" alt=""> </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a class="submenu-link"href="#"">чотири весілля</a></li>
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href=https://1plus1.ua/odruzhennya-naoslip>одруження наосліп</a></li>
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">на ножах</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-program"><a class="menu-link" href="#">серіали <img src="img/Rectangle 43 copy 9.png" alt=""> </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">хороший хлопець</a></li>
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">життя після життя</a></li>
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">останній москаль</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-program"><a class="menu-link" href=#>фільми <img src="img/Shape 32 copy 7.png" alt=""> </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">діти пермоги</a></li>
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">розщеплені на атоми</a></li>
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">я з тобою</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-program"><a class="menu-link" href=#>ведучі <img src="img/Shape 32 copy 9.png" alt=""> </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">Ведучі</a></li>
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">Ведучі</a></li>
      <li><a class="submenu-link" href="#">Ведучі</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если Вы хотите картинку добавить - [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/677265/edit)

Comment: перекиньте `:hover` с `a` на родительский `li` как в моём ответе

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev  помогло спасибо))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cабменю должно быть внутри раздела меню:

```
<nav>
  <li>
    <a href="#">меню</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">подраздел 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">подраздел 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">подраздел 3</a></li>
    <ul>
  <li>
</nav>
```

Тогда стилями хватать ховер на li

```
nav > li > ul { display: none }
nav > li:hover > ul { display: block }
nav > li:hover > a { color: red }
```